# Eliminate accents in python

Tags: python, unicode, diacritics

I have this function to remove accents in a word

```
def remove_accents(word):
    return ''.join(x for x in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', word) if x in string.ascii_letters)
```

But when I run it it shows an error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The character in position 3 is : ó

Comment: Works for me, if the input is a unicode string: `remove_accents(u"foóbar")` correctly returns `u"foobar"`

Comment: You think that it may be because I'm working on a Mac?

Comment: No, I'm on a Mac, too.

Comment: When I enter a character with accent it shows this: Unsupported characters in input

Comment: How are you entering those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is a unicode string, it works:

```
>>> remove_accents(u"foóbar")
u'foobar'
```

If it isn't, it doesn't. I don't get the error you describe, I get a TypeError instead, and only get the UnicodeDecodeError if I try to cast it to unicode by doing

```
>>> remove_accents(unicode("foóbar"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If that is your problem, i.e. you have Python 2 `str` objects as an input, you can solve it by decoding it as utf-8 first:

```
>>> remove_accents("foóbar".decode("utf-8"))
u'foobar'
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly my problem, I tried decoding it as utf-8 but it shows this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 3: unexpected end of data

Comment: Just a wild guess, but try `"cp1252"` instead of `"utf-8"`